# Alternatives when pattern matching in Racket

Tags: pattern-matching, racket

I want to match one of the following two lists in Racket (formerly PLT Scheme):

```
'(somename : (_ptr o sometype))
```

or

```
'(somename : (_ptr io sometype))
```

As you can see, the only difference is the literals 'o and 'io in the embedded list.

I can see two basic ways to do this.

Either:

```
(match myexpr 
    [(list name ': (list '_ptr 'o _)) name]
    [(list name ': (list '_ptr 'io _)) name]
    [_ 0])
```

which seems like duplication of the effort, but is very clear. Or:

```
(match myexpr 
    [(list name ': (list '_ptr mode _)) 
      (if (or (eq? mode 'o) 
              (eq? mode 'io))
     name
     0)]
    [_ 0])
```

which avoids the almost duplicated patterns, but is much less clear.

My question is, is there a way to specify alternatives in racket pattern matching, something along the lines of {'o | 'io}? And, if not, which of the two ways outlined above would be the most idiomatic Racket way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an `or` pattern `(or 'o 'io)`.  And of course, don't forget that all of this is [documented](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html).

Comment: Thanx - dunno how I missed that, since I actually looked for it. No, really :-)